# How to make Auto sum blank before values in range are entered? Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to make an auto sum in excel. It is easy by using =SUM(C5:F5).(I doing this at cell G5). And it comes out with an 0 in G5 before I input anything inside the C5:F5.

What I want is to make the G5 blank, before any value input in the C5:F5. And if there is any value input in either one cell in C5:F5, then only the G5 show the result.

I tried already the formula =IF(ISBLANK(C5:F5), "", SUM(C5:F5)), but it came out same as =SUM(C5:F5), a 0 is there.

Anyone can suggest solution?

Comment: If it came out as =SUM(C5:F5), then the test is false. So, are there any expressions in those cells? I also saw where, if all cells are numeric, you can test for count instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(C5:F5)=COLUMNS(C5:F5),"",SUM(C5:F5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way would be:

IF(SUM(C5:F5)="";"";SUM(C5:F5))

Take note that if any 0 is entered in the columns C5:F5, a 0 will be displayed.